# Flutter, Mockito: How to mock a method with named parameters?

Tags: flutter, dart, unit-testing, hive, mockito

I am trying to test a datasourse class that using the Hive library for storing data.

I wrote this code for test:

```
// import ...
import 'my_datasource_hive_test.mocks.dart';

@GenerateNiceMocks([
  MockSpec<BoxCollection>()
])

void main() {
  test(
    'MyDatasourceHive Constructor',
    () {
      // Assign
      final mockMyCollection = MockBoxCollection();
      final datasource = MyDatasourceHive(
        collection: mockMyCollection,
      );
    },
  );
```

Then I run the command for generate the MockBoxCollection class:

`flutter pub run build_runner build`

And when I run tests I have next error:

`The parameter 'boxCreator' of the method 'MockBoxCollection.openBox' has type 'CollectionBox/*1*/<V> Function(String, BoxCollection)?', which does not match the corresponding type, 'CollectionBox/*2*/<V> Function(String, BoxCollection)?', in the overridden method, 'BoxCollection.openBox'.`

Comment: Can you possibly remove code to create a minimal but complete example that can reproduce this problem?  My best guess would be that you somehow have two classes both named `BoxCollection`.  If so, the most common cause of that is using a case-insensitive file system and using inconsistent capitalization in `import`s.

Answer (score 0):

The error you received suggests that the parameters in `MockBoxCollection.openBox` and `BoxCollection.openBox` don't match. Try this:

- Update the mokito package with the `flutter pub upgrade mockito` command.
- If that doesn't fix the issue, maybe try using a different library like [mocktail](https://pub.dev/packages/mocktail)
- Another suggestion would be to update the `MockBoxCollection` to match the `BoxCollection` interface, by referring to Hive's documentation.